# Calculate percentages on ranges

Tags: sql, group-by, range, percentage

I have the following table with data:

```
+----------+------------+-----------+
| country  | age        | gender    |
+----------+------------+-----------+
| China    |    15      |  male     |
+----------+------------+-----------+
| China    |     25     |   female  |
+----------+------------+-----------+
| China    |     50     |  male     |
+----------+------------+-----------+
| China    |     62     | male      |
+----------+------------+-----------+
| Burma    |     25     |   female  |
+----------+------------+-----------+
| Burma    |     50     |  male     |
+----------+------------+-----------+
| France   |    27      | male      |
+----------+------------+-----------+
| France   |    55      | female    |
+----------+------------+--------- -+
```

I want to query select with the following result:

```
+----------+-----------+---------+-----------+-----------------+----------------+
| region   | age_range |  gender | count     | gender_percent  | total_percent  |
+----------+-----------+---------+-----------+-----------------+----------------+
| Asia     |  0-49     | male    |   1       |     33          |   12.5         |
+----------+---------- +---------+-----------+-----------------+----------------+
| Asia     |  0-49     | female  |   2       |     67          |   25           |
+----------+-----------+---------+-----------+--------------- -+----------------+
| Asia     |  50+      | male    |   3       |   100           |   37.5         |
+----------+-----------+---------+-----------+-----------------+----------------+
| Europe   | 0-49      | male    |   1       |    100          |  12.5          |
+----------+-----------+---------+-----------+-----------------+----------------+
| Europe   | 50+       | female  |   1       |    100          |  12.5          |
+----------+-----------+------- -+-----------+-----------------+----------------+
```

Ie. I want to calculate different percentages on ranges of data. One percentage for gender to each range of countries (region) and age range, and one percentage relative to the total count.

How do I do this?

I will prefer a cross RDBMS solution, which is as less hard coded as possible. Speed and simplicity are also major dimensions. I am developing on MySQL but the solution will later be ported to Oracle as well as MS SQL.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Partial solution similar to 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4645322/how-to-group-number-of-users-by-age-bands-in-mysql

Comment: Why are people down rating this question? I cannot find similar question, only small parts of it. The question is not only about ranges.

Comment: Region must be hard coded same as age ranges, i.e. that China and Burma belong to Asia and so forth. Thx.

Comment: from where you get region?

Comment: You cant do that. You need that data in some where. Sql isnt google maps

Comment: @HenrikHansen Yes ,either you have to store region data in DB and then join table and map it or use hardcoded query to tell that this country belongs to this region.

Comment: If I can case when `age`<50 then `0-49`I guess I can do same with region case when `Burma` then ´Asia`? Or why not?

Comment: @naruto, yes both solutions will be suitable and interesting. Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I put region as a column in country. In the select I use CASE to get range label. You can do the same for `region` if dont want add the `region` field

```
CREATE TABLE country
    (`region` varchar(6), `country` varchar(6), `age` int, `gender` varchar(6))
;

INSERT INTO country
    (`region`, `country`, `age`, `gender`)
VALUES
    ('Asia', 'China', 15, 'male'),
    ('Asia', 'China', 25, 'female'),
    ('Asia', 'China', 50, 'male'),
    ('Asia', 'China', 62, 'male'),
    ('Asia', 'Burma', 25, 'female'),
    ('Asia', 'Burma', 50, 'male'),
    ('Europe', 'France', 27, 'male'),
    ('Europe', 'France', 55, 'female')
;
```

[**SqlFiddleDemo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/970256/7)

```
SELECT region.*, 
       (count_range_gender / region_range_total.gender_total) * 100 as gender_percent,
       (count_range_gender / world.world_total) * 100 as total_percent
FROM 
    (
      SELECT `region`,
             CASE WHEN age < 50 then '0-49' 
                  ELSE '50+'
             END age_range,
             gender, 
             count(country) as count_range_gender
      FROM country
      GROUP BY `region`,
               CASE WHEN age < 50 then '0-49' 
                    ELSE '50+'
               END,
               gender
      ) region
JOIN 
    (
      SELECT `region`,  
              CASE WHEN age < 50 then '0-49' 
                  ELSE '50+'
              END age_range, 
              count(country) as gender_total
      FROM country   
      GROUP BY `region`,
               CASE WHEN age < 50 then '0-49' 
                    ELSE '50+'
               END
     ) region_range_total
  ON region.region = region_range_total.region
 AND region.age_range = region_range_total.age_range
CROSS JOIN 
    (
      SELECT count(country) as world_total
      FROM country         
     ) world
```

**OUTPUT**

```
| region | age_range | gender | count_range_gender | gender_percent | total_percent |
|--------|-----------|--------|--------------------|----------------|---------------|
|   Asia |      0-49 | female |                  2 |        66.6667 |            25 |
|   Asia |      0-49 |   male |                  1 |        33.3333 |          12.5 |
|   Asia |       50+ |   male |                  3 |            100 |          37.5 |
| Europe |      0-49 |   male |                  1 |            100 |          12.5 |
| Europe |       50+ | female |                  1 |            100 |          12.5 |
```

**EDIT**

In MySql you can also use `IF(age < 50, '0-49', '50+')`

Comment: Nice solution. However, in the SQLFiddleDemo the total_percent is wrongly calculated... (I had made it wrongly for gender_percent for Europe, which I have corrected). Thanks a lot so far :-)

Comment: Also, how to do it, if the region info is not in the source table? Thanks again.

Comment: @HenrikHansen If the region info is not in the source table, you must tell us where it is in your database schema... Actually, not only the region info, but the association between the region info and the country...

Comment: The region info is supposed to be hard coded (or be in a separate region table) - same as the age ranges. Thx.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the full answer. Anyway, I wouldnt have been able to make it without the answer from @Juan Carlos Oropeza. Thanks again to Juan :-)

```
SELECT region.*, 
   (`count` / region_range_total.gender_total) * 100 as gender_percent,
   (`count` / (select count(*) from country)) * 100 as total_percent
  FROM 
   (
    SELECT
      CASE country 
        WHEN 'China' then 'Asia'
        WHEN 'Burma' then 'Asia'
        WHEN 'France' then 'Europe'
      END region,
      CASE WHEN age < 50 then '0-49' 
         ELSE '50+'
      END age_range,
      gender, 
      count(country) as `count`
  FROM country
  GROUP BY 
      region,  
      age_range,
      gender
  ) region
JOIN 
  (
  SELECT 
      CASE country 
        WHEN 'China' then 'Asia'
        WHEN 'Burma' then 'Asia'
        WHEN 'France' then 'Europe'
      END region,  
      CASE WHEN age < 50 then '0-49' 
          ELSE '50+'
      END age_range, 
      count(country) as gender_total
  FROM country   
  GROUP BY 
      region, 
      age_range
 ) region_range_total
 ON region.region = region_range_total.region
 AND region.age_range = region_range_total.age_range
```

Comment: You could use `WHEN country IN ('China', 'Burma') THEN 'Asia' ELSE 'Europe'`.

Comment: Yes, that's even better :-) Thx.

Comment: good, Just try to avoid use field names like `count` because those are reserved words in the sql lenguaje and can be confusing.

Comment: @Juan Carlos Oropeza, I fully agree with you. In real life, I would always prefix variables for several reasons...