# SELECT CASE with aggregation functions

Tags: mysql, case

I have three tables: indi (individuals), consump (consump) and manu (manufacturer)

I would like to group the individuals by age categories (I have the actual ages) and show the total volume consumed by manufacturer.

So something like this:

```
Age Category | Manufacturer | Total Volume Consumed 
15 - 24      | Coca Cola    | 10ML
             | Pepsi        | 25 ML
```

Now following this example ([How to group number of users by age bands in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4645322/how-to-group-number-of-users-by-age-bands-in-mysql)), I created age bands as follows:

```
SELECT
CASE
WHEN age >=15 AND age <=24 THEN '15-24'
WHEN age >=25 AND age <=34 THEN '25-34'
WHEN age >=35 AND age <=44 THEN '35-44'
WHEN age >=45 AND age <=54 THEN '45-54'
WHEN age >=55 AND age <=66 THEN '54-64'
WHEN age >=65 THEN '65+'
END AS ageband
```

The keys which link the tables are `id` for the `indi` and `consump` tables and `code` linking the `consump` and `manu` tables. Now multiple codes are attached to one manufacturer, as a manufacturer produces more than one type of drink.

So the `where` clause would include the following:

`indi.id = consump.id AND consump.code = manu.code`

So my thinking process is as follows (I do realise that I need to include the case statement, but I have no idea where I put it - somewhere as a subquery? )

```
SELECT age, manufacturer, SUM(volume) as 'Total Volume Consumed'
FROM indi, consump, manu
WHERE indi.id = consump.id AND consump.code = manu.code
GROUP BY ageband
```

Comment: Add it to the column list with and alias of ageband

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just add  the case and the proper group by

```
    SELECT CASE 
        WHEN age >=15 AND age <=24 THEN '15-24'
        WHEN age >=25 AND age <=34 THEN '25-34'
        WHEN age >=35 AND age <=44 THEN '35-44'
        WHEN age >=45 AND age <=54 THEN '45-54'
        WHEN age >=55 AND age <=66 THEN '54-64'
        WHEN age >=65 THEN '65+'70
        END  as ageband
        , manufacturer
        , SUM(volume) as 'Total Volume Consumed'
    FROM indi
    INNER JOIN consump ON indi.id = consump.id
    INNER JOIN manu ON consump.code = manu.code
    GROUP BY ageband, manufacturer
```