# SQL query ALL in One - To avoid number of queries

Tags: php, mysql

I  have been trying to generate report as per age differences of different months the solution currently i know is to make separate sql queries for each month and each age difference separately which results to create 4 different sql queries for each month. Kindly let me know is it possible to create one sql query for each month like

If i want to generate report for JAN for age differences of Above 40, In Between 50 - 60, In between 60-70 and above 80

How can i put it in one sql queries and get four different results from it

Something like (an idea only)

```
Select count(Above 40),count(In Between 50 - 60),count (In B/W 60-70), count(above 80) from users
```

Comment: Yes it's possible. You should look into the GROUP BY statement. That's all I can say at the moment. I don't understand your data structure very well and what you want to fetch so that's all I can help you with at the moment.

Comment: This question might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2870783/mysql-group-by-and-bracketing-according-to-age

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd use the IF() and SUM() together as follows:

```
SELECT SUM(IF(age >= 40,1,0))               AS older40, 
       SUM(IF(age >= 50 and age <= 60,1,0)) AS between50and60
       SUM(IF(age >= 60 and age <= 70,1,0)) AS between60and70
       SUM(IF(age >= 80,1,0))               AS over80

FROM TABLE
```

Refer to the MySQL explanation for [IF(expr1,expr2,expr3)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if), but basically expr1 is the condition, expr2 is the value when the condition is true and expr3 is the else. Using 1 & 0 for these allows the SUM() to count the records.

Comment: kindly let me know 70,1,0 mean if this true then value is 1 else 0. Right? and thanks your solution worked.

Comment: IF(age > 70,1,0) would return 1 if age was greater than 70 and 0 if less than 70

Comment: one last question how can i use the `select YEAR( NOW( ) ) - YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME( i_dob ) as year, SUM(IF(year >= 40,1,0))  ` and use year at different places i tried the above query but got error so what's the appropriate way to use it thanks..

Comment: I don't think that you can do that without using an SQL function

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
Select Range,Count(*) From
(Select 
Case 
When (Age >= 40 and Age < 50) Then 'Above40'
When (Age >= 50 and Age < 60) Then 'Between 50 - 60'
When (Age >= 60 and Age < 70) Then 'In B/W 60-70'
When (Age > 80) Then 'Above 80'
else 'Not Counted'
end as Range
From Users) as Ranges
Group By Range
```

Guessed at the guards as you seem to have a number of gaps and overlaps in them.

Answer (score 0):

```
select *
from (
(select COUNT(Age) as `c1`, '40-50' AS 'freq' from `Users` WHERE Age BETWEEN 40 AND 50)
UNION ALL
(select COUNT(Age)  as `c2`, '50-60' AS 'freq' from `Users` WHERE Age BETWEEN 50 AND 60)
UNION ALL
(select COUNT(Age)  as `c2`, '60-70' AS 'freq' from `Users` WHERE Age BETWEEN 60 AND 70)
) as aliasquery ;
```

Comment: that's still going to run many queries and the original question was how to avoid number of queries.

Comment: its technically one query command.  never said it was elegant.  question is answered anyhow