# Delete "almost duplicate" rows based on coordinate proximity

Tags: sql, sqlite, sql-delete, exists

I have a table with names of towns, municipality, county and coordinates. Unfortunately, some towns have "near duplicates", i.e. there exists another row with the same name, municipality, county and coordinates very near the first row. Some even have more than one "near duplicate".

How can I remove all but one of these kinds of rows?

I know I can use a CTE with `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY name, municipality, county, latitude, longitude)` to delete exact duplicates. But how can I check if the latitude and longitude are, say, within `0.005` (=roughly 500-600 meters with lat/lng in decimal degrees) of each other?

##### Sample data

```
ID  Name         Municipality   County  Lat         Lng
------------------------------------------------------------
1   Springfield  Simpsonville   Homer   12.34567    89.01234
2   Springfield  Simpsonville   Homer   12.35000    89.01200
3   Springfield  Simpsonville   Homer   12.00000    89.00000
4   AnotherTown  AnotherVille   Bart    12.34567    89.01234
```

Since `2` has the same name, municipality and county as `1`, and is within `0.005` decimal degrees in both latitude and longitude of `1`, it is considered a duplicate and should be deleted.
`3` on the other hand is not within `0.005` decimal degrees of `1`, so it should *not* be considered a duplicate of `1`.

##### Expected result

```
ID  Name         Municipality   County  Lat         Lng
--------------------------------------------------------
1   Springfield  Simpsonville   Homer   12.34567    89.01234
3   Springfield  Simpsonville   Homer   12.00000    89.00000
4   AnotherTown  AnotherVille   Bart    12.34567    89.01234
```

Comment: How do you calculate proximity? Post sample data and expected results to clarify what you want.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL Group By and bracketing according to age](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2870783/mysql-group-by-and-bracketing-according-to-age)

Comment: Sample data and resired results please

Comment: @forpas Sample data and expected results added. Please read the question properly for how to calculate proximity.

Comment: @Stu There, now you have sample data and expected results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `EXISTS` in the `DELETE` statement:

```
DELETE FROM tablename AS t1
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 
  FROM tablename t2
  WHERE (t2.Name, t2.Municipality, t2.County) = (t1.Name, t1.Municipality, t1.County)
    AND ABS(t2.Lat - t1.Lat) <= 0.005 AND ABS(t2.Lng - t1.Lng) <= 0.005
    AND t2.ID < t1.ID
);
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=03337d4caba3a25f5bb783ab6ff67d73).